# My EER diagram doesn't show the editing tool

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm on mac air m2 and for some reason the eer diagram in model doesn't show the editing tool and because of that I cant create tables and create relationship for its. The script work normally

As seen in the imagine, normally there will be a editor part where I can click on to create table and relationship but it is not there for some reason.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGfiE.png)

I tried to reinstall and intall it couple time with different versions but it didn't work.

Comment: You should raise this problem with mysql support, there is little we can do about bugs in a compiled application.